# Can´t use jQuery on dropdown-item from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, dropdown

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SignIn').click(function(){
    $('#test').css('color','red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Iniciar Sesión</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="LogIn" href="#">Iniciar Sesión</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="SignIn" href="#">Registrarse</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="CerrarSesion" href="#">Cerrar Sesión</a>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- None important code lines -->
<div class="starter-templates" id="test">
  <h1>ESTA ES MI PÁGINA WEB DE CITAS</h1>
</div>
```

Here I am just creating a click event when you click #SignIn. To make sure it works I am just changing the color to a h1 text whose id is test.

**strong text**

This is Bootstrap´s first example to learners like me.I have modified the code a little. When I add a click event with jQuery for a dropdown-item from Bootstrap it doesn't´t work. I am using the example from bootstrap web-page. It does work if the click event is set to another item such a nav-link class. New to StackOverflow. Thank you very much.

Comment: "it doesn't´t work" means your dropdown won't work if you add a click event with jQuery for a dropdown-item?